# Image upload in database - NULL (OOP)

Tags: php, mysql, image, oop, null

Profile image won't upload in database. It get's uploaded in folder, but in database it just says NULL.

Code:

```
if (Input::exists()) {
    if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        try {
            $user->update(array(
                'image' => $title
            ));

            if (isset($_FILES["image"])) {
                $title = date("dmyHms") . "_" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                $path = "img/profile/" . $_POST["id"] . "_" . $title;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

This is solution, it saves image in database:

```
$user->update(array(
       'image' => 'image',
       'image' => $title
));
```

Comment: If you're using laravel, go full laravel. Do `Input::only('file_goes_here')->move(base_path() . 'path/to/folder');`. With that said, I see you're updating the user's image, rather than inserting a new one. Are you sure that's what you wish to do? Not to mention you're updating where `image`...meaning every user.

Comment: I'm not using laravel, image get's uploaded in folder, database is problem..

Comment: My bad then, syntax seemed very laravel-like. Anyway, you're still updating every user in the db. What is the `$title` variable exactly?

Comment: I tried with insert but then I get new id, rather to just set image on user_name.. I got confused couse I tried so many variations.. I will post DB.php class and User.php class

Comment: Looks like you're not passing the $id to the user->update() function

Comment: Username, name etc. update without problem, but image won't.

Comment: I successfully inserted image with this code, but problem is that it isn't by user id, it make new one... How can I fix that? I put code after the DB.class